# What is the equivalent command in SourceTree GUI of 'git add .'?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to use SourceTree GUI. I've successfully created a local repo, committed some adds, removes, and mods, also successfully pushed to my remote.

My problem is, everytime I try to commit, the 'Staged Changes' file list in my commit window is empty, and I must manually drag and drop the content of 'Working Copy Changes' filelist to the 'Staged Changes'.

I figured out, if I issue the 'git add .' command in my terminal, then the very same thing happen.

Is there any way not to do this allways before my commits?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this answer from Atlassian](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39543/how-to-stage-multiple-files-in-sourcetree), you can multi-select files (Cmd-A to select all) in the File Status View and once you've selected them, click 'Add' or press Cmd-+ (Shift-Cmd-=)

Alternatively, once you have pushed the `Commit` button, the commit dialog has a checkbox to the left of the text `Unstaged files`. If you check it, you will immediately stage all files that are currently listed as unstaged:

[image: Unstaged files part of commit dialog]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out the same a few years ago, just could not believe how can a _GUI_ be so unintuitive...Why I have to drag and drop for _each_ commit? (and pay attention do not drop any ignored, to force add them?. Why can not be the _default_ adding everything what changed and _not_ in the .gitignore?. Still the most robust and almost the fastest way to open a terminal (most left in the toolbar) and issue "git add ." before the commit. After the first occasion it is just 2 keypress: Up then Enter...